# Bind a delegate to an event dynamically

Tags: c#, reflection, delegates

I have a method which binds methods on a page to `LinkButton`s that are created dynamically.

```
protected virtual void AddDynamicHandlerToControl(Page page, Control controlInstance,
            string methodName, string eventName)
{
   Delegate d = null;

   EventInfo ei = controlInstance.GetType().GetEvent(eventName);

   Type tDelegate = ei.EventHandlerType;

   MethodInfo method = page.GetType().BaseType.GetMethod(methodName, BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

   if (method != null)
      d = Delegate.CreateDelegate(tDelegate, page, method);
   else {
      FieldInfo field = page.GetType().BaseType.GetField(methodName, BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

      if (field != null)
      {
         d = field.GetValue(page) as Delegate;
      }
   }

   MethodInfo addHandler = ei.GetAddMethod();
   object[] addHandlerArgs = { d };
   addHandler.Invoke(controlInstance, addHandlerArgs);
}
```

This works for methods inside that page. What I wanted to add is support for methods inside user controls. So I created a `delegate` in the page code-behind and assign it the user control method at runtime.

I create and assign the delegate like so:

```
protected event PrintPageMethod PrintPage;
protected delegate void PrintPageMethod(object sender, EventArgs e);
```

and then:

```
PrintPage = DetailedTestsResult1.UserActionsForTests1_PrintPage;
```

The code tries to find a method, when one is not found it tries to find a field for the delegate and finds the correct delegate, which points at the correct method with the user control class as the target.

The problem is that when `addHandler.Invoke(controlInstance, addHandlerArgs);` is reached, it throws as exception

> Object of type 'SomePage+PrintPageMethod' cannot be converted to type 'System.EventHandler'.

and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: show the complete user control (event related things)

Comment: @jgauffin - I would have added the usercontrol code, but since a delegate is a pointer to a function, I don't see the relevance of showing the function itself. The exception is not about assigning the function to the delegate, but about assigning the delegate to the event hanlder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
protected event PrintPageMethod PrintPage;
protected delegate void PrintPageMethod(object sender, EventArgs e);
```

use:

```
protected event EventHandler PrintPage;
```

In spite of similar signatures, delegate *types* are different.

Comment: That seems like a workaround, not a fix. The code seems like it is supposed to see that the `PrintPage` event has type `PrintPageMethod` and create a `PrintPageMethod` delegate.

Comment: Thanks! Event if this is a workaround (and I still don't understand why using a delegate did not work), this solves my problem.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot cast Delegate to other Delegate.

```cs
d = field.GetValue(page) as Delegate;
```

to

```cs
Delegate orig = field.GetValue(page) as Delegate;
d = Delegate.Combine(
    orig.GetInvocationList()
    .Select(_ => Delegate.CreateDelegate(tDelegate, _.Target, _.Method))
    .ToArray()
    );
```

You can create another `Delegate` using invocation target from `.Target` and `.Method`, and if the Delegate has many targets, you've to combine each delegates.